# HTML in front of FLASH

Tags: html, flash, overflow, absolute

im working with flash and I would like to create HTML5 control bar for my FLASH player. And my problem is positioning HTML in front of flash. I can position HTML as "absolute", but then the overflow settings of box it is inside aren't working. Could someone tell me, how to position HTML in front of flash without absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, as always - I've found solution after posting for help.

If someone would be experiencing the same problem;

Position parent element to "relative", and then you can safety set "absolute" for child element. Cheers!